# How to pass the value of previous row to current row?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How can I pass the result of previous row to the computation of the current row

Given the unit and the cost, I need to get the average cost of each transactions:

The formula:

1. Average cost is the sum of transaction cost
2. If Type is Sub then Trx cost is equal to cost
3. If Type is Red then Trx cost is Unit * (sum of previous trx cost/sum of previous units)

```
|  Row | Type | Unit | Cost | TrxCost  | Ave_cost |
|  1   |Sub   | 0.2  | 1000 |  1000    | 1000     |
|  2   |Sub   | 0.3  | 2500 |  2500    | 3500     |
|  3   |Sub   | 0.1  | 600  |  600     | 4100     |
|  4   |Red   |- 0.2 |-1100 | -1366.67 | 2733.33  |
|  5   |Sub   | 0.3  | 1000 |  1000    | 3733.33  |
|  6   |Red   | -0.6 | -600 | -3200    | 533.33   |
```

Update:

Order is based on row number.

Thanks.

Comment: What column identifies which one is the previous row ? Without that how do you know which one is current and which one is previous?

Comment: I added row number. Thanks!

Comment: Also, when you say sum of previous rows , does it mean sum of Cost?

Comment: Sum of the trx cost. Thanks for reminding

Comment: How do you get TrxCost = -3200 in the last row? With your formula I get: -0.6 * (1000+2500+600-1100+1000) / (0.2+0.3+0.1-0.2+0.3) = -3428.57

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use Recursive CTE

```
WITH cte (row_num,
     type,
     unit,
     sum_of_unit,
     cost,
     trxcost,
     ave_cost
) AS (
     SELECT row_num,
            type,
            unit,
            unit AS sum_of_unit,
            cost,
            cost AS trxcost,
            cost AS ave_cost
     FROM t
     WHERE row_num IN (
          SELECT MIN(row_num)
          FROM t
     )
     UNION ALL
     SELECT t.row_num,
            t.type,
            t.unit,
            c.sum_of_unit + t.unit AS sum_of_unit,
            t.cost,
            CASE t.type
                 WHEN 'Sub'   THEN t.cost
                 WHEN 'Red'   THEN t.unit * ( c.ave_cost / c.sum_of_unit )
            END
       AS trxcost,
            c.ave_cost + CASE t.type
                 WHEN 'Sub'   THEN t.cost
                 WHEN 'Red'   THEN t.unit * ( c.ave_cost / c.sum_of_unit )
            END AS ave_cost
     FROM t
     JOIN cte c ON t.row_num = c.row_num + 1
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

[**Dbfiddle Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=847069763b2953cf5c09428dcae5684b)

Comment: Hi @kaushik Nayak this is great. but trx cost and ave cost are not given and needs to be computed first. only given are unit and cost.

Comment: @just10 : This solution has already taken that into consideration. You should see the updated dbfiddle and use this query.

Comment: Nice! this is really great but I'll accept thorsten answer for being shorter code. Hope you understand :)

Comment: @just10 : Length of code should be the least of your criteria to make a decision. You should check the performance of both codes and use the one which works best for you and importantly, it should give you the correct result. I may reformat the code and reduce the number of lines of the query for you, but that's not the point. But, again, you are free to chose.

Comment: I agree that the length of the query should not trigger the decision. Especially when the query results are different, as is the case with our queries. I like the CTE approach. Right now your query depends on consecutive row numbers, but these could easily be generated anyway.

Comment: I guess you are right Kaushik, Thorsten answer is much faster than yours but he summed up the cost instead of ave cost in getting trx cost, while yours is, so far, accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two passes: one to get `theTrxCost`, then one to get the `Ave_cost`.

What you are calling "average" is a running total by the way; you are merely adding up values.

You need window functions with `ROWS BETWEEN` clauses. (In case of `SUM(...) OVER (ORDER BY ...)` this is implicitly `BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT`, however).

```
select 
  id, type, unit, cost, round(trxcost, 2) as trxcost,
  round(sum(trxcost) over (order by id), 2) as ave_cost
from
(
  select 
    id, type, unit, cost,
    case 
      when type = 'Sub' then cost 
      else
        unit *
        sum(cost) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) /
        sum(unit) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
    end as trxcost
  from mytable
)
order by id;
```

I renamed your `row` column `id`, because `ROW` is a reserved word.

The last row's results differ from yours. I used your formula, but get different figures.

Rextester demo: https://rextester.com/ASXFY4323

Answer (score 0):

See the [SQL Window Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_window_function) , which allow you to access values from other rows in the result set. In your case, you will need to tell us some more criteria for when to stop looking etc.:

```
select
    lag(unit,1) over (partition by type order by whatever) 
  * lag(cost,1) over (partition by type order by whatever)
from Trx
```

But I'm still missing how you want to correlate the transactions and the reductions to each other. There must be some column you're not telling us about. If that column (PartNumber?) is known, you can simply group by and sum by that.

Comment: I already tried that, but my problem is, I have to compute first the average cost of the previous row, then use the result to calculate the average cost of current row.